# Getting adjacent objects to interact [C#]

Tags: c#

I'm doing a basic game in C#, and I'm running up on a problem I can't solve. Here's the (relevant) code:

```
public class GameManager
    {
        public GameMap MainMap;
        public EntityManager GameWorld;
        public SystemManager GameSystems;

        public GameManager()
        {
            EntityManager GameWorld = new EntityManager();
            SystemManager GameSystems = new SystemManager();
            GameMap MainMap = new GameMap(61, 41);
        }

        public void InputHandler(string Trigger)
        {
            switch (Trigger)
            {
                case "north":
                    GameSystems.Move(GameWorld, MainMap, 0, 8);
                    break;
                 //etc
             }
        }
    }

    public class SystemManager
    {
       public rkcPosition _position;

       public SystemManager()
       {
       }

       public bool Move(EntityManager TargetWorld, GameMap TargetMap, int TargetID, int TargetDirection)
        {
            rkcPosition _position = TargetWorld.GetPosition(TargetID);
            // here, GetPosition returns an instance of rkcPosition
            // pulled from a List<rkcPosition> - this seems to be the problem point
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm getting is with the part where I try to call `GameSystems.Move` - it jumps to highlight the last line of the code I included (w/rkcPosition) and gives a `null ref exception`. (rkcPosition is a class I've not included in this code snippet)

I'm trying to have the Move function perform some changes to values within the `GameWorld` and `MainMap` objects. I'm beginning to think I'm doing this all wrong, so...

If I want to run a method on my existing instances "GameWorld" and "GameSystems" from the `InputHandler function`, how would I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sami Kuhmonen said, the problem in your code is that you are constantly passing around and reassigning your objects that are essentially supposed to be global. Not only does this require that you pass them as parameters to anything that would need them, it is also incredibly error-prone (as you have discovered).

Instead of having these objects behave like instance objects, utilize the Singleton design.

What this means is that instead of instance members, these objects are static members that represent a single global object for everything else to access.

```
public class GameManager
{
    public static GameMap MainMap;
    public static EntityManager GameWorld;
    public static SystemManager GameSystems;

    static GameManager()
    {
        GameWorld = new EntityManager();
        GameSystems = new SystemManager();
        MainMap = new GameMap(61, 41);
    }

    //...
}
```

Now in your other classes, instead of having to worry if you are passing around the correct object, simply reference these singletons from the GameManager.

```
public class SystemManager
{
    public rkcPosition _position;

    //...

    public bool Move(int TargetID, int TargetDirection)
    {
        rkcPosition _position = GameManager.MainMap.GetPosition(TargetID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly redefining variables inside methods that override the member variables. As your debugger shows the `GameWorld`, `MainMap` etc are null and you're trying to use them. I don't know how it even goes to `Move()` since the member variable `GameSystems` will also be null.

Remove the definitions of the variables inside the methods, that way you're actually storing the objects somewhere and not throwing them away immediately after the method is over. For example:

```
public GameManager()
{
    GameWorld = new EntityManager();
    GameSystems = new SystemManager();
    MainMap = new GameMap(61, 41);
}
```

Comment: I figured I was doing everything wrong. So if I have a class instance with data stored inside it, and I want to operate upon that data using a method, how do I appropriately send that object to be operated upon? For example, CharacterObject contains the integer X, which is currently "4". I want to send it to a function that will change it to be "5" while otherwise keeping it intact.

Comment: @user1002617 Depends on what you mean by "send." There's nothing else wrong with your code than hiding the class variables with method variables and that can be fixed the way I showed.